# Fila con maxima cantidad de "X" elemento

Tags: python

quisiera saber como puedo devolver la fila que tiene la máxima cantidad de "X" elemento, en base a la información recolectada sobre el tablero.
Tengo un tablero de 5x5(5  filas y 5 columnas). Si yo encontré que la 2° fila tiene la máxima cantidad de elementos, ¿Cómo hago para denotar esa fila?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta... Si tu tablero es una lista (de listas), el primer elemento `tablero[0]` corresponderá a la primera fila, etc. La segunda fila será  `tablero[1]` (aunque depende de cómo lo imprimas luego por pantalla, y de cómo cuentes tú las filas, ya que al imprimir irás normalmente de arriba a abajo, pero al decir "segunda fila", a lo mejor quieres decir la segunda desde abajo, que sería entonces `tablero[-2]`)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando preguntas denotar esa fila, interpreto que es detectar cual es.

En este caso sabiendo el indice te basta. En python los indices empiezan por el 0 por lo que en este ejemplo de tablero 3 x 3 la fila con más X es la 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


def buscaFilaConMasX(l):

    index = 0
    nEquis = 0
    for i in range(0,len(l)):

        if (l[i].count('X') > nEquis):
            nEquis = l[i].count('X')
            index = i

    return index

tablero = [ [3,3,3] , [3,3,3], [3,3,3] ]

tablero[0][2] = 'X'
tablero[1][1] = 'X'
tablero[1][2] = 'X'
tablero[2][0] = 'X'

print(tablero)
print(buscaFilaConMasX(tablero))
```

Y aqui el output:

```
[[3, 3, 'X'], [3, 'X', 'X'], ['X', 3, 3]]
1
```

Espero que sea eso lo que preguntabas, sino escríbeme un comentario